# When I include <script> tags in another PHP file the javascript code doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I've been stuck on this issue for a while now. Maybe some of you programming geniuses can help me out.

So I am working with 6 files:

1. BASE_URL/header.php
2. BASE_URL/footer.php
3. BASE_URL/includes/notifications.php
4. BASE_URL/includes/wall.php
5. BASE_URL/javascript1.js
6. BASE_URL/javascript2.js

   The header.php file includes the  tag for javascript1.js.

   The footer.php file includes the  tag for javascript2.js.

   The notifications.php file gets the messages and alerts and has some html in it and calls a function from the wall.php.

   The wall.php file gets the messages from the database and has some html in it.

   The javascript1.js file has some ajax that refers to the notifications.php

   The javascript2.js file has some javascript.

Everything works fine. Except that the javascript code in my javascript2.js file doesn't seem to be working. And when I include the  tag within the notifications.php file it causes some errors please help.

Here is the code for the javascript1.js

```
/*---------------- popoup message notifications -----------------*/
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{/* this function will be available after the document is loaded */

    /* declare the message notification variables */
    var messagesIcon    = $('.page_header_messages_icon');
    var messagesInboxList   = $('.messages_popup_box_inbox_list');

    /* declare the ajaxAutoAlerts variable */
    var ajaxAutoAlerts;

    /* call the autoLoadMessages function */
    autoLoadMessages();

    messagesIcon.click(function(event)
    {/* when the messagesIcon is clicked */

        /* show the ajax loader */              
        jQuery(messagesInboxList).html("<div class='load_notifications' align='center'><img src='"+site_url+"img/ajax-loader.gif' /></div>"); 

        var dataString = 't=alrt';

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: site_url+"includes/message_notifications.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(response){

                jQuery(messagesInboxList).html("");
                jQuery(messagesInboxList).html(response);

                /* resize nicescroll everytime an element using nicescroll is shown/hidden */ 
                niceScrollVariable.getNiceScroll().resize();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you show us those *"errors"*?

Comment: Well it seems to interfere with some of my other javascript code. Like when I click the an icon for a popup box I have to click it more than once. And it disables other javascript popups from opening.

Comment: if `javascript2.js file doesn't seem to be working` then you should share this file

Comment: You said that there are some erros showing up in you console, in order for us to help you, we'll need to see those. I didn't even notice that you didn't share the right file even, second that @Rishi

Comment: BTW, `jQuery(messagesInboxList)` should be `messagesInboxList`

Comment: It exceeds the maximum number of characters allowed...